# What is the substitute for LengthUnit.ZeroCharacterWidth?

Tags: gembox-spreadsheet

I am using GemBox.Spreadsheet, and just updated the NuGet packages to the latest version.  I am getting a compiler warning now that states LengthUnit.ZeroCharacterWidth is obsolete.  What is the new, correct way to do this?  This routine autofits columns.

[image]

Comment: For what is the `width` variable used? Is it just for that `lines` calculation or?
I presume that you'll want to use `LengthUnit.CharacterWidth`, see: https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/docs/GemBox.Spreadsheet.LengthUnit.html